# javascript settimeout keeps going faster and faster?

Tags: javascript

I am making a snake game in JavaScript, so if I press on an arrow key the 'snakehead' should keep moving in that direction.

The first time I press a key it's doing it nicely, but after that the head keeps moving faster and faster.

So what I want is something that moves the head once every 100 millisceconds. If you don't really get what i mean then have a look at this page: http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/snake.html

So, can someone tell me how to change my code so that it keeps running at same speed?

```
function init_game() {
    if ((event ? event.keyCode : down) == (event ? 40 : 1)) /*down*/
    {
        if ((snakehead + z) < z * z) {
            right = 0;
            left = 0;
            up = 0;
            down = 1;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gamebox";
            snakehead = snakehead + z;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gameboxsnake";
        } else {
            document.write("<h1>game over!</h1> press this button to try again.<br><input     type='button' value='retry'     onclick='window.open(\"http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/snake.html\",\"_self\")'>");
        }
    }
    if ((event ? event.keyCode : up) == (event ? 38 : 1)) /*up*/
    {
        if ((snakehead - z) > -1) {
            right = 0;
            left = 0;
            up = 1;
            down = 0;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gamebox";
            snakehead = snakehead - z;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gameboxsnake";
        } else {
            document.write("<h1>game over!</h1> press this button to try again.<br><input    type='button' value='retry'    onclick='window.open(\"http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/snake.html\",\"_self\")'>");
        }
    }
    if ((event ? event.keyCode : right) == (event ? 39 : 1)) /*right*/
    {
        if ((snakehead + 1) % z !== 0) {
            right = 1;
            left = 0;
            up = 0;
            down = 0;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gamebox";
            snakehead = snakehead + 1;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gameboxsnake";
        } else {
            document.write("<h1>game over!</h1> press this button to try again.<br><input     type='button' value='retry'   onclick='window.open(\"http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/snake.html\",\"_self\")'>");
        }
    }
    if ((event ? event.keyCode : left) == (event ? 37 : 1)) /*left*/
    {
        if (snakehead % z !== 0) {
            right = 0;
            left = 1;
            up = 0;
            down = 0;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gamebox";
            snakehead = snakehead - 1;
            document.getElementsByClassName(snakehead, "div", document)[0].id = "gameboxsnake";
        } else {
            document.write("<h1>game over!</h1> press this button to try again.<br><input   type='button' value='retry' onclick='window.open(\"http://www.dbzweb.be/08/braetj08/snake.html\",\"_self\")'>");
        }
    }
    t = 0;
    t = setTimeout("init_game()", 100);
}
```

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you posted an illegible wall of code. Please take some time to review the [faq], and **invest your time** into writing a good question, otherwise it's not worth investing my time into writing a good answer.

Comment: [Indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style)

Comment: Just a note: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.  Pass function instead: `t = setTimeout(init_game, 100);`.

Comment: i removed the quotes and that just made it worse

Comment: @JannesBraet: Note, how I didn't say "remove the quotes", I said pass a function.  `setTimeout(init_game, 100);` (note the lack of `()` after `init_game`).  That wasn't a solution, just an FYI.

Comment: @zzzzBov: its like 4 times the same so not that hard to read over it. and i just wanted to show it to make sure that all variables are made clear a bit

Comment: It's speeding up because you never stop looping the `init_game` function.  Each key press runs it again, which keeps looping itself.  So the `init_game` is "running" multiple times, that's why its speeding up.

Comment: thank you veeeeeeeeeeery much rocket =D

Comment: @JannesBraet, it was illegible **because** it was a wall of code. My point was that you need to spend more time reviewing questions before posting them, rather than hoping someone in the community will be kind enough to tidy up your mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = 0;
t = setTimeout("init_game()", 100);
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.  This sets the variable `t` to 0 (this *doesn't* clear the timeout), and then immediately sets it to the `timeoutID` returned from `setTimeout`.

The snake is speeding up, because each time a key is pressed `init_game` is ran again, thus increasing the amount of timeouts runnning all calling `init_game` again.

Try changing `t = 0;` to `clearTimeout(t)`.  You'll need to declare `t` before your code, though (add `var t;` to the top).

Also, don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.  Pass functions.

```
clearTimeout(t);
t = setTimeout(init_game, 100);
```

Note: after you `document.write("<h1>game over!</h1>` you should add `return;` to stop `init_game` from looping (and printing infinite "game over!" messages).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/T5kPg/1/